# if else in nsdictionary

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have a dictionary of array:

```
    array3 = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:docpath2] retain];
```

no problem here. now i have 
an NSString *temp which contains some numbers.
i would like to check whether this number exist in the dictionary, not each array.

```
    if([array3 valueForKey:temp])
```

is this right? doesn't the if loop execute if its true?

```
<dict>
     <key>123456</key>
     <array>
        <string>low</string>
        <string>High</string>
     </array>
      <key>78910</key>
    <array>
         <string>low</string>
         <string>High</string>
     </array>
  </dict>
```

for example temp = 78910, i would like it to be found.

thks in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get your question, but I'll give it a shot.

First, `objectForKey:` is the method to use as `valueForKey:` is for Key-Value Coding and will give you strange results should your key start with an @.

Then, if `objectForKey:` does return a pointer (i.e. the return value is not `nil`/`NULL`/`0`) then the key exists and has a value (which was returned). So yes, you can do:

```
if ([array3 objectForKey:temp]) {
  // Do something, the dictionary does contain a value for
  // the key referenced by "temp".
}
```

Now, if your keys a strings like `@"123"`, then you can of course do `[array3 objectForKey:@"123"]`. But if you got an integer, then you would need to do `[array3 objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 123]]`.

Also note that you can also use `NSNumber` or `NSValue` as keys. So you could do:

```
[myMutableDictionary setObject:someObject forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]];
myValue = [myMutableDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]];
if (myValue) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine. Why do you think it's not working?